# My DeLonghi coffee machine is broken. I probably need a sealing ring

Tags: coffee-machines

I have a DeLonghi coffee maker.

Recently the water has been leaking past the water tank. I looked up on the internet what the possible causes could be. Here I found that then probably the sealing ring is worn or defective. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Welcome! We can certainly help you with an analysis of potential damage (a photo of the gasket would be helpful, as well as the exact model), but discussion of a specific web shop is not ok - it’s either opinion based or may be seen as spam attempt, both require the post to be closed. I recommend you take the [tour] and browse through the [help], especially [ask], to learn more about how the site works.

Comment: It's hard to see from here. Any chance you could add a picture or two of what you think are the problem areas? People would just be speculating otherwise, and we like to give better advice than that.  :-)